# Cannot get my html input array to serialize into a List<string> in Asp.Net mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, serialization, model-binding

I am attempting to implement a tagging system into my asp.net MVC project.  When a user edits or adds a task, they can add any amount of tags they want before submitting.  I am using the Jquery Tagit plugin, so when a user adds a new tag an input field is created that looks like:

```
<input type="hidden" style="display:none;" value="tag1" name="Tags[]">
```

When the user presses the submit button after adding a few tags, the browser sends the following querystring to the server (retrieved via fiddler):

```
IsNew=True&Id=2222&Title=Test+Title&Description=Test+Description&Tags%5B%5D=Tag1&Tags%5B%5D=blah&Tags%5B%5D=another-tag
```

Now my viewmodel that I am serializing this data into has the following structure:

```
public class KnowledgeBaseTaskViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false, ErrorMessage="Task title is required")]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false, ErrorMessage="Task description is required")]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
    public bool IsNew { get; set; } // Needed to determine if we are inserting or not
}
```

Finally my receiving action has the following signature:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditTask(KnowledgeBaseTaskViewModel task)
```

The issue is that my tag list is not serializing correctly, and my List Tags is null.  I have looked at various questions on this site on how to serialize arrays but I still cannot see what I am doing wrong.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you've got should work, but try changing the type of Tags property from List to IList.  the model binder might not be using the concrete List<> type.

also, check out this article by Phil Haack: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: IList<string> doesn't appear to be binding either :-/

Comment: I checked out the link.  Everything I'm doing seems to be in line with what they are saying to do.

Comment: remove the square brackets from the `name="Tags[]"`

Comment: Interesting idea.  I'll give that a try first thing when I get back to work on Monday, thanks!