# How do you serialize a JS array so Asp.net MVC can bind it to a c# list?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, arrays

I am trying to send a jquery sortable list of items to my MVC method for data processing.  Currently I am trying to send it via the following code:

```
var data = {};
data.projectId = projectId;
data.publishedSectionIds = $('#section_list').sortable('toArray');

// Perform the ajax
$.ajax({ url: '/Project/Publish',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.message);
    } 
});
```

The problem with this code is it makes the Post parameters look like this:

```
projectId=2&publishedSectionIds[]=1&publishedSectionIds[]=2
```

The issue with this (as can be seen by the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317981/cannot-get-my-html-input-array-to-serialize-into-a-liststring-in-asp-net-mvc)) is that MVC only seems to serialize into a List if the post parameters do *NOT* have brackets.

How can I serialize the javascript array so my action with a `List<int>` parameter model binds correctly?

---

**Edit:** The action's signature looks like:

```
 public ActionResult Publish(int projectId, List<int> publishedSectionIds)
```

Comment: can we see your action signature?

Comment: alright, see my answer, i have two different actions that both work wonderfully :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding the following option traditional: true

eg

```
$.ajax({ url: '/Project/Publish',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    traditional: true,
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.message);
    } 
});
```

see

> As of jQuery 1.4, the $.param() method serializes deep objects recursively to accommodate modern scripting languages and frameworks such as PHP and Ruby on Rails. You can disable this functionality globally by setting jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Comment: Nope that didn't seem to help at all.  The query string still has brackets in it and ASp.net MVC still can't serialize it in the traditional format.  The `List<int> publishedSectionIds` isn't null, but it has a count of zero

Comment: Not really sure why `traditional: true` didn't work before, but now it is  I probably messed up elsewhere.  Marking this as the answer since he answered a while ago and it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

alright here's something i just wrote now that works!

here's the action:

```
Public Overridable Function PostProject(ByVal model As Project) As ActionResult
    Return Json(model.PublishedSectionIds)

End Function
```

here's the class:

```
Public Class Project
    Public Property ProjectId As Integer
    Public Property PublishedSectionIds As IList(Of Integer)
End Class
```

here's the javascript:

```
        var data = {};
        data.ProjectId = 1;

        data.PublishedSectionIds = $('#section_list').sortable('toArray');
        var url=  "/testing/tester";
        $.ajax({ 
            url:url,
            type: 'POST',
             traditional: true,
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
```

ignore the fact that my action is overridable. that's just from t4mvc.

i tried it with the list being and IList or a List, both work just fine.

hope that helps!

Edit:

I also tested it w/o the model like so:

```
    Public Overridable Function PostProject2(ByVal ProjectId As Integer, ByVal PublishedSectionIds As List(Of Integer)) As ActionResult
        Return Json(PublishedSectionIds)

    End Function
```

add it worked just fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle it completely in JS (you may need to edit line 2 - I have assumed that you are using a list and are trying to pull the id attribute itself)

```
var data = "projectId=" + projectId;
$("#section_list li").each(function(){ data += "&publishedSectionIds=" + this.id;});
$.ajax({ url: '/main/test',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.message);
    } 
});
```

or if you want to make sure you are using sortable('toArray') data (although the above result also provides the sorted data)

```
var data = "projectId=" + projectId;
var tempData = $('#section_list').sortable('toArray');
$.each(tempData, function(index, value){ data += "&publishedSectionIds=" + value;});
$.ajax({ url: '/main/test',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.message);
    } 
});
```

Comment: the sortable('toArray') returns an array of the id's in order.  what he's doing there is quite correct.

Comment: Yes, even this method returns the id's in order but removes the [] from the posted data.
I edited the code to use the sortable('toArray') data if preferred.

Answer (score 0):

When I pass in JavaScript arrays into my post method, i type them as an `int[]` not `List<int>`.

Try this if you haven't.

Comment: Not sure who this message was for, but with my code example, the ASP.net server-side should see it as:
projectId=2&publishedSectionIds=1&publishedSectionIds=2
which should be readable by the List<int>